# Best Approach for displaying web Services Data in android

Tags: android, gridview, tableview, android-arrayadapter

I have to display web Services Data Either in Tabular form or in Grid form.Where rows and columns of the grid view dynamically increase or decrease.
Every column must have an header.
All the things including header ,images ,no of rows and columns of Grid view can change either product wise or Number of No of item wise.

Means There are No. of product and a Product have No. of Item and its properties.All these thing i have to display either in Grid view or in table view.Where header, images of product or item,and No. of rows and columns can change Dynamically.

What would be the best way to implement this.Does the custom Adapter for displaying the a dynamic table would be helpful.

Please Guide me.New In Stack Over Flow.

Comment: [This might help you out . Dynamic grid view with th e custom adapter implementation.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021528/dynamic-gridview-items-in-android

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem.